# Kivy/PyInstaller - Windows Packaging - Problem with additional dependency

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, pyinstaller

I've been trying to follow https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html

but I have additional libraries[Watchdog/S2Protocol] that I'm using with this program. I've compiled it using all of the basic instructions on the site but when I run it in cmd I'm getting the following error:

```
 WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\test\\COMPIL~1\\dist\\SC2_GO~1\\s2protocol\\versions\\*.*'
[15264] Failed to execute script compile_test
```

I've been searching for a while but can't find anything relevant on this topic and I'm not sure how to add the dependency while using PyInstaller to fix this issue. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: .spec file reads:

```
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\test\\compile_test.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\test\\compile_here'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='sc2_goal_tracker',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('C:\\test\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='compile_test')
```

Comment: You may need to consider this [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/runtime-information.html#using-file-and-sys-meipass).  You should post a [mcve] for us to give you informed answers, but least post the `.spec` file that `Pyinstaller` created.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Sorry about that. Due to my lack of knowledge I wasn't sure what information I should provide exactly to help resolve the issue. I have updated the question with my .spec file after I edited it as from the tutorial. I will try to post more information in my questions in the future.

Comment: Your `.spec` will create a `one folder` executable. The files that your app is looking for should be in your `dist` folder. You can use the `datas` element of `Analysis` object to specify files to be included. See the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle) for instructions on how to add files by editing the `.spec` file. Also, very importantly, once you have edited your `.spec` file, you run `Pyinstaller` as `pyinstaller <spec file name>`. Running `Pyinstaller` without the `.spec` file name will overwrite the `.spec` file.